# RTTI property not found for CPP targets in Haxe NME

Tags: c++, types, rtti, haxe, nme

I'm using rtti in haxe nme. It works well when targeting flash but when compiling to a cpp target I receive the following error.

error C2039: '__rtti' : is not a member of 'Class_obj'

I'm doing this...

```hx
public function doSomething(type:Class<Dynamic>):Void {
    var typeInfo:String = untyped type.__rtti;
}
```

I also tried...

```hx
public function doSomething <T:Infos> (type:Class<T>):Void {
    var typeInfo:String = untyped type.__rtti;
}
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it looser! `:Dynamic` instead of `:Class<Dynamic>`

```hx
public function doSomething(type:Dynamic):Void {
    var typeInfo:String = untyped type.__rtti;
}
```